# Taylor-approximation of square root

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, approximation

Can someone please guide me with this question: Use the Taylor polynomial of $$f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$$ around $0$ to get an estimate for $\sqrt{2}$ correct to
one decimal places (that is, remainder less than $0.05$). State clearly the polynomial you are using. First give the solution as a fraction, then use a calculator to write the solution with one decimal precision. Use a calculator to verify that the solution is correct.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\,\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\,\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Indeed, the use of
>   $\ds{\root{\vphantom{\large A}1 + x}}$ to evaluate approximately $\ds{\root{\vphantom{\large A}2} =
> \root{\vphantom{\large A}1 + \color{#f00}{1}}}$ $\ul{is\ not}$ very convenient because the $\ds{\root{\vphantom{\large A}1 + x}}$ Taylor expansion converges for $\ds{\verts{x} < 1}$. The following approach provides a simple evaluation which is 'fully' convergent ( it's more or less borrowed from the numerical stuff ):

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\root{\vphantom{\large A}2}} & = \root{98 \over 49} =
{1 \over 7}\root{\vphantom{\large A}{100 - 2}} =
{10 \over 7}\root{{1 - {1 \over 50}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{10 \over 7}\bracks{%
1 - {1 \over 100} +
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose  n}\pars{-\,{1 \over 50}}^{n}}
\\[5mm] & =
{10 \over 7}\bracks{%
1 - {1 \over 100} +
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{n - 3/2 \choose  n}\pars{1 \over 50}^{n}}
\\[5mm] & \ds{=}
{10 \over 7}\bracks{%
1 - {1 \over 100} +
{1 \over 2500}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n + 1/2 \choose  n + 2}\pars{1 \over 50}^{n}}
\\[5mm] & =
{10 \over 7} - {1 \over 70} +
{1 \over 1750}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n + 1/2 \choose  n + 2}\pars{1 \over 50}^{n}
\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

$$
\begin{array}{c}
\ds{\mbox{Numerical evaluation of}\
\root{2} = 1.41421356237309\ldots}
\\[2mm]
\pars{~\mbox{which can be compared with the following table}~}
\end{array}
$$

---

From expression $\ds{\pars{1}}$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rclc}&&& \mbox{Error}\\[8mm]
\hline
\ds{10 \over 7} & \ds{\approx} & \ds{1.4\color{#f00}{2\ldots}} & \ds{1.0153\ \%}
\\[3mm]
\ds{99 \over 70} & \ds{\approx} & \ds{1.4142\color{#f00}{8\ldots}} &
\ds{5.1019 \times 10^{-3}\ \%}
\\[3mm]
\ds{19\ 799 \over 14\ 000} & \ds{\approx} & \ds{1.41421\color{#f00}{4\ldots}} &
\ds{5.1148 \times 10^{-5}\ \%}
\\[3mm]
\ds{1\ 979\ 889 \over 1\ 400\ 000}  & \ds{\approx} & \ds{1.4142135\color{#f00}{7\ldots}}&
\ds{6.4032 \times 10^{-7}\ \%}
\\[3mm]
\ds{22\ 627\ 417 \over 16\ 000\ 000}  & \ds{\approx} & \ds{1.414213562\color{#f00}{5\ldots}}&
\ds{8.9735 \times 10^{-9}\ \%}
\\&&&
\\ \hline
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 4):

*Just for your curiosity.*

Following Dr. MV's answer, let us consider the more general case where you would like a remainder less that $\epsilon$. Then, as Dr. MV wrote,  you are looking for $n$ such that $$\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(2n-1)}<\epsilon\tag 1$$ For approximating the lhs, use [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) which is $$m!\sim \sqrt{2 \pi m} \left(\frac m e\right)^m$$ This makes $(1)$ much simpler since it becomes $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{n} (2 n-1)}<\epsilon\tag 2$$ and we can write  $$\frac{1}{2n\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{n} }<\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{n} (2 n-1)}<\epsilon\tag 3$$ from which $$n >\frac 1{(2 \sqrt{\pi}\epsilon)^{2/3}}\approx \frac{0.43}{\epsilon ^{2/3}}\tag 4$$ Since $n$ is an integer, then select $$n=\left\lceil \frac{0.43}{\epsilon ^{2/3}}\right\rceil\tag 5$$

For your case where $\epsilon=0.05$, the above formula would lead to $n=4$. To $\epsilon=0.005$ would correspond $n=15$. As Dr. MV mentioned, it is possible that one less term could be resuired. For the last considered remainder, summing up to $n=15$ leads to $$\frac{95064943}{67108864}\approx 1.41658$$ but $n=14$ leads to $$\frac{47365319}{33554432}\approx 1.41160$$ which is also within the prescribed tolerance of $0.005$.

Comment: Did you mean lhs? The rhs is just $\epsilon$, the factorials to be approximated are on the lhs.

Comment: @njuffa. Thanks for pointing the typo ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3):

The Taylor series for $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$ is given by

$$f(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} (2n)!x^n}{4^n(n!)^2(2n-1)}$$

Inasmuch as the series is an alternating series, the error of the $N-1$'th partial sum for $x=1$ is bounded by $\frac{(2N)!}{4^N(N!)^2(2N-1)}$.  We want to find $N$ such that the error is less than $0.05$.  Thus, we set

$$\frac{(2N)!}{4^N(N!)^2(2N-1)}<0.05$$

which is satisfied for $N\ge 4$.   Therefore, the square root of $2$ can be approximated to one decimal place as

$$\sqrt{2}\approx 1+\frac12-\frac18+\frac1{16}=\frac{23}{16}\approx 1.4375$$

However, we can check numerically that for $N=3$, the approximation

$$\sqrt{1+x}\approx 1+\frac12-\frac18 \approx 1.375$$

is also within the prescribed tolerance of $0.05$.

Comment: Just to add to this, the Taylor expansion can also come from Newton's General Binomial Theorem: $$(1+x)^{a/b}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a/b)(a/b-1)(a/b-2)\cdots(a/b-n+1)}{n!}x^n$$, where $a/b=\frac12$

Comment: @JasonM The GBT is, of course, a Taylor series.